# Rails Route Broke - no code changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a model competitions that allows users to attend and withdraw from a competition. It was working well and I was changing other aspects of the site. I tested the withdraw again and the code is broken.

From a competition when I click withdraw it takes me to a page:

`No route matches [GET] "/competitions/1/withdraw"`

I ran `$ rake routes` and received

```
  attend_competition POST   /competitions/:id/attend(.:format)   competitions#attend
                 GET    /competitions(.:format)              competitions#index
                 POST   /competitions(.:format)              competitions#create
                 GET    /competitions/new(.:format)          competitions#new
edit_competition GET    /competitions/:id/edit(.:format)     competitions#edit
                 GET    /competitions/:id(.:format)          competitions#show
                 PUT    /competitions/:id(.:format)          competitions#update
                 DELETE /competitions/:id(.:format)          competitions#destroy
withdraw_competition POST   /competitions/:id/withdraw(.:format) competitions#withdraw
                 GET    /competitions(.:format)              competitions#index
                 POST   /competitions(.:format)              competitions#create
                 GET    /competitions/new(.:format)          competitions#new
                 GET    /competitions/:id/edit(.:format)     competitions#edit
                 GET    /competitions/:id(.:format)          competitions#show
                 PUT    /competitions/:id(.:format)          competitions#update
                 DELETE /competitions/:id(.:format)          competitions#destroy
            root        /
```

When I withdraw it goes to the url: `http://0.0.0.0:3000/competitions/1/withdraw`

my config routes.rb file is

```
...
resources :competitions, only: [:create, :destroy, :new, :index]
...
resources   :competitions do
  post 'attend', on: :member
end
resources :competitions do
  member do 
    post 'withdraw'
  end
end
```

any help would be appreciated.

**More Info**

So, I have verified that my html should be sending a post request

```
    <% if @competition.users.exclude?(@user)  %>
  <%= link_to 'Attend Competition', attend_competition_path(@competition.id), :method => :post %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Withdraw', withdraw_competition_path(@competition.id), :method => :post %>
```

And they are send Get requests.

I also found that my server isn't able to find jquery-ujs which is related

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
```

and finally my gemfile currently:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.3.0'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

Comment: Looks like your route requires a `POST` and you are doing a `GET`.  Di d the view or JS change?

Comment: yes, I changed it back to just //=require jquery /n //=require bootstrap, but this hasn't fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

Check your HTML.

If it is a link triggering withdrawals check to make sure you have `method: :post` set. If it is a form, check that too. Either way, inspect the HTML you are actually getting from rails. If you still can't figure it out go ahead and post it.

#### Edit

Change

```
//= require jquery-ujs
```

To

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, there is no route that matches `"/competitions/1/withdraw"` with a get method. You have specified `post` in your routes:

```
post 'withdraw'
```

If you want a get request as well, you can do this:

```
resources :competitions do
  member do 
    match 'withdraw', via: [:get, :post]
  end
end
```

Or you can change your link to make a post request by using `method: :post` in the options hash. See [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) for more details.

Comment: posted more detailed information on the question. thanks